# MKPolyline polylineWithPoints bug?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I want to display a route from my location to a destination.
I took this code http://code.google.com/p/octomapkit and I have added a few logging messages.
Go got the route coordinates ( around 103) properly. They are on the way and filling the route from my location to destination, so the google call and parsing the elements is good.
But when I want to display in MKMapView than it shows only the starting the polyline. Like 15 or 20 not more.

I will try to post the code from top to bottom:

The original code took the first element only and I was thinking maybe if I get the last I will see something else, if yes, than I will add all overlays - that's why the for loop.

otherwise :  `MKPolyline *polyLine = [self.mapView.overlays objectAtIndex:0];`

```
#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *routeLineView = nil;
    // should take the objectAtIndex:0 , but for test I will check if it has more
    for(int i=0;  i <self.mapView.overlays.count; i++ ){

        MKPolyline *polyLine = [self.mapView.overlays objectAtIndex:i];       

        routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:polyLine] autorelease];
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;   
    }   

    return routeLineView;
}


-(void) routeLoadSucceededWithRoutePoints:(MKMapPoint*)routePoints count:(int)pointNumber {
    //NSLog(@"MKMapVew+OctoRoute.routeLoadSucceededWithRoutePoints count: %d", pointNumber);

    MKPolyline* routeLine = nil;
    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:routePoints count:pointNumber];

    // add the overlay to the map
    if (nil != routeLine) {

        // added zoom support:
        if(shouldZoom){
            MKCoordinateRegion region = [self coordinateRegion];
            [self setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }


        //[self removeOverlays:self.overlays];
        [self addOverlay:routeLine];
    }
}
```

the `//[self removeOverlays:self.overlays];` has no effect if is commented or not,  Iwas hoping it will create more :) -but not.

Inside `mapPointCArrayFromJSONString` I see the coordinates properly:

```
-(void) jsonLoadSucceededWithData:(NSData*)loadedData {
    self.routeParser.jsonStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:loadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = [self.routeParser mapPointCArrayFromJSONString];

    //NSLog(@"OctoRouteService.jsonLoadSucceededWithData : %d"+ mapPointCArray.);
    [delegate routeLoadSucceededWithRoutePoints:mapPointCArray count:[self.routeParser numberOfPoints]];
}
```

The `steps` has the coordinated for sure. Checked many times.

```
-(MKMapPoint*) mapPointCArrayFromJSONString {   
    NSArray *steps = [self routeStepsArrayFromJSONString];

    //NSLog(@"OctoRouteParser.mapPointCArrayFromJSONString steps:%d ", steps.count);
    if(steps.count == 0){
        return nil;
    }

    MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [steps count]*2 -1);
    numberOfPoints = [steps count]-1;

    int index=0;
    for (NSDictionary *stepDict in steps) {
        [self addRouteStepDict:stepDict toMapPointCArray:mapPointCArray atIndex:index];
        index = index+2;        
    }

    return mapPointCArray;
}
```

I can't see a reason why is only the first fraction of the route on my map, with red line.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewForOverlay` delegate method will be called by the map view for each overlay it needs to display a view for.  It may also call it more than once for each overlay.

Your code only needs to worry about creating and returning a view for the single `overlay` *passed as a parameter* to that method.

The code there should be something like this:

```
MKPolylineView *routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];
routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;   
return routeLineView;
```

The existing code in your question returns the view corresponding to the last overlay that happens to be in the `overlays` array for every overlay the map view calls `viewForOverlay` for.

---

Additionally, that octomapkit has a bug in the `mapPointCArrayFromJSONString` method.  These lines:

```
MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) 
                                        * [steps count]*2 -1);
numberOfPoints = [steps count]-1;
```

should be:

```
MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) 
                                        * [steps count]*2);
numberOfPoints = [steps count]*2;
```

The original first line is wrong because it excludes the end point of the last line segment.

The original second line is very wrong because `numberOfPoints` is supposed to reflect the number of points in the `mapPointCArray` (not the last index in the `steps` array).  The way it was, the overlay would only show half the route.

It would be cleaner to change that code so the calculation is done only once:

```
numberOfPoints = [steps count]*2;
MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) 
                                        * numberOfPoints);
```

The `viewForOverlay` method should still be coded as explained earlier.  It should only work with the `overlay` parameter passed to it and not directly with the map view's `overlays` array.

Comment: // should take the objectAtIndex:0 , but for test I will check if it has more

Comment: anyhow I have tested the suggested code, and no improvement: has the same result

Comment: That did the job: numberOfPoints = [steps count]*2;
MKMapPoint *mapPointCArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) 
                                        * numberOfPoints);